# How to move a pair of lines to the end of preceding pair of lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a large file with a repeating 5 line pattern starting with a datestamp. I'm trying to move (relative) lines 4 and 5 to the end of lines 2 and 3 respectively:

current output:

```
Mon Mar  2 16:47:14 UTC 2020
    1        90    93090     1024        0        0        0    93090|
    9        73    74877     1024        0        0        0    74877|
  Dirty Cache:          860160 KB
  Dirty Cache:          0 KB
Mon Mar  2 16:47:15 UTC 2020
    1        68    69680     1024        0        0        0    69680|
    9        83    85838     1024        0        0        0    85838|
  Dirty Cache:          860160 KB
  Dirty Cache:          0 KB
Mon Mar  2 16:47:16 UTC 2020
    1        66    67794     1024        0        0        0    67794|
    9        67    68806     1024        0        0        0    68806|
  Dirty Cache:          860160 KB
  Dirty Cache:          0 KB
Mon Mar  2 16:47:17 UTC 2020
    1        42    43424     1024        0        0        0    43424|
    9        47    48473     1024        0        0        0    48473|
  Dirty Cache:          860160 KB
  Dirty Cache:          0 KB
```

Desired output with the dirty cache values at the end lines starting with '1' and '9':

```
Mon Mar  2 16:47:14 UTC 2020
    1        90    93090     1024        0        0        0    93090|  Dirty Cache:          860160 KB
    9        73    74877     1024        0        0        0    74877|  Dirty Cache:          0 KB
Mon Mar  2 16:47:15 UTC 2020
    1        68    69680     1024        0        0        0    69680|  Dirty Cache:          860160 KB
    9        83    85838     1024        0        0        0    85838|  Dirty Cache:          0 KB
Mon Mar  2 16:47:16 UTC 2020
    1        66    67794     1024        0        0        0    67794|  Dirty Cache:          860160 KB
    9        67    68806     1024        0        0        0    68806|  Dirty Cache:          0 KB
Mon Mar  2 16:47:17 UTC 2020
    1        42    43424     1024        0        0        0    43424|  Dirty Cache:          860160 KB
    9        47    48473     1024        0        0        0    48473|  Dirty Cache:          0 KB
```

This output is being generated from printing `date` and then looping a proprietary command to produce the numeric values:

```
while sleep 1; do date && proprietary 'numerical values command' && proprietary 'dirty cache command 1' && proprietary 'dirty cache command 9'; done >2020-03-02_stats.txt
```

...then using some basic grep to omit the column headers and output for 2 thru 8's numerical values.

Unfortunately, I can't separate the numerical values output with the command being used, i.e., printing output '1' and then dirty cache values for '1', which would make this a simple job for sed.

However, because of the multiple lines involved, I don't see how to keep these correctly sorted in sed's pattern space function. I'm guessing I should be using awk at this point, but i'm not sure how to tackle it. any tips?

Comment: If it's always going to be 5 lines, it's very easy. Do it in `awk`. First, store 5 lines in an array. Then after each 5 lines, output them in the format you want with `printf`. Like `awk '{a[FS%5]=$0} FS%5==4{ printf "%s,%s", a[0], a[1] }'`. A `sed` solution would also be easy: first read 5 lines at a time and then just regex them all to shuffle them: `sed 'N;N;N;N;s/\([^\n]*\)\n([^\n]*\)\n([^\n]*\)\n([^\n]*\)\n([^\n]*\)/\1\n\2|\3\n\4|\5/'`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply - I'm getting a few errors with these solutions (on a Mac) but can try them in RHEL shortly and at the very least, the N;N;N;N; setup is steering me in the right direction. thanks!

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{a[NR%5]=$0} NR%5==0{printf "%s\n%s%s\n%s%s\n",a[1],a[2],a[4],a[3],a[0]}'
```

Save 5 lines into an array `a`. Then if the current line is divisible by 5, print the line with shifted order.

Comment: Thanks again @KamilCuk, this one worked right out of the box. I much appreciate all the other replies though, gives me a lot to digest. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk '
  NR%5==1                    # print this line
  NR%5==2{ first=$0 }        # save this line in variable first
  NR%5==3{ second=$0 }       # save this line in variable second
  NR%5==4{ print first $0 }  # print first and this line
  NR%5==0{ print second $0 } # print second and this line
' file
```

Comment: Looks like you could use a few more next statement in the code just for consistency - or remove a couple.  As I see it, each  input line  will only trigger one of your conditions, so you can remove all your next statements or add some more.  Or you can leave it alone :).  All that being said, I like your solution better than mine in as much as it's simpler and thus easier to understand.

Comment: @Mark I removed the next statements, thanks! The shorter the better.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish your task you can indeed use `sed`. The following command is effective:

```
sed -E 'N;N;N;N;s/\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)$/\2\n\1\3/' your_file
```

It works essentially as KamilCuk explained in his comment, which I hadn't read when I posted my answer, except that

- the `-E` option helps keeping the regex a bit shorter (search for it in `man sed` to see what it does),
- you don't need to match the line 2, as the `\n`s are enough to pinpoint where each line begins/ends.

Comment: No need to apologize, your `sed` _command_ is actually formed differently and works where his returns `sed: -e expression #1, char 82: Unmatched ) or \)`

Comment: Oh, now that I look at his one better, I have only matched 3 lines, not 4. And the pipes are in the input already. OK, I feel better now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awk solution for you:

```
awk '/^[^ ]/ { 
  for ( x = 1 ; x <= linecount ; x++ ) 
    { print lines[x] "" dc[x] }
  linecount = 1 
  dclinecount = 1 
  print
  next
}
/Dirty Cache:/ {
  dc[ dclinecount++ ] = $0
  next
}
{ 
  lines[ linecount++ ] = $0
}
END { 
  for ( x = 1 ; x <= linecount ; x++ )
    { print lines[x] ""  dc[x] }
} 
'
```

The awk program has several assumptions.  Here's the first one:

1. On line 1, we assume that only a date starts at the beginning of
   the line.
2. On line 2, we assume that the number of Dirty Cache lines is than or equal to  the number of preceding lines.  If there are more Dirty Cache line, the program will not work (data will not be put out for the extra Dirty Cache lines ).

While this script is not very general, it can support an arbitrary number of data lines and Dirty Cache lines with the above caveat ( #2 ).

Answer (score 0):

Another possible short solution in GNU `awk`, which processes the file according to your description:

- It uses the string `Mon` as the record separator `RS`, so that each record is a set of 5 lines
- It uses the newline `\n` as the field separator (both in input, `FS`, and output, `OFS`)
- Then it prints the 5 fields in the desired order, prepending the `RS` and interspersing the `OFS` appropriately by means of the comma operator `,`.

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "Mon"; FS = OFS = "\n" } NR > 1 { print RS $1, $2 $4, $3 $5 }' your_file
```